# Elements become invisible on reload, then get visible again on resize

Tags: php, html, browser, frontend

I'm working on a website and hit my head with some basic display problem.

I want to use a php variable that holds a value from the database which represents the ***src*** attribute of an *img* tag. I do this in 2 different places, once in the navbar (where it works perfectly fine) and once inside another *div*, which causes a big portion of the page (along with the image container) to become blank when the page is reloaded. It works fine if I resize the window or open the Dev Tools.

This is the code that I use for displaying the image in both places:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_index=?;";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            echo $_SESSION['dbError'];
        } else {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $index);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

            if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $responsible = $row;
                }
            } else {
                echo $_SESSION['dbError'];
            }
          mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
       }

if ($responsible['avatar'] == 'noAvatar') {
            echo '<i class="material-icons">person</i>';
        } else {
            echo '<img src="images/icons/' . $responsible['avatar'] . '">';
        }
```

`$responsible` is the row from the database that contains the column *avatar* with the value `[someName.extension]` e.g. "koala.png".

If I replace the *img* element with some random string, everything works fine, that's how I found out where the problem may be:

```
if ($responsible['avatar'] == 'noAvatar') {
            echo '<i class="material-icons">person</i>';
        } else {
            echo 'This displays fine';
        }
```

Here are some pictures that can exemplify the issue better:

[picture displayed as wanted (inside the navbar)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVaeZ.png)

[blank element after reloading the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqfLK.png)

[Everything displayed fine after window resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypxmx.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem - Materialize CSS. It was not that I tried to get the image source from the database as I thought, but because I was trying to add an image inside the content of **Materialize CSS** tabs component.

Apparently, Materialize tabs are based on the CSS carousel, which, in some cases has the height set to a certain amount by the style attribute of the element.

The issue was in the *div* with the class "tabs-content" which was automatically created by the Materialize tabs and had a fixed height of 400px normally, and 30px when an image is inside that *div*.

Here is the code that I added to my styles.css file in order to fix it and set its height big enough in order to fit all the content:

```
.tabs-content.carousel.carousel-slider .carousel-item.active {
  position: relative;
}

.tabs-content {
  height: auto !important;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

I hope this helps if anyone else has or will have the same problem.